# Как передать изображение из flash в php

Tags: flash, php

Вопрос собственно в заголовке. Интересует конкретно формат в котором php корректно сможет его поймать.

Answer (score 1):

примерно так:

```
// ActionScript 3
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
// Пустой  битмап 100*100пикс.
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, false, 0xFFFFFF);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
// Кодируем в байтмассив JPG формата.
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(myBitmapData); 
var fileName:String='Name';
jpgStream.writeMultiByte("_s_"+fileName,"us-ascii");
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myJpgSaver.php");
request.requestHeaders.push(header);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = jpgStream;
// Отсылаем на сервер.
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");   
myBitmapData.dispose();

//myJpgSaver.php
<?PHP
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    $parts=explode("_s_", $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);
    $name=$parts[1];    
    $fp = fopen( $name.".jpg", 'wb' );  
    fwrite( $fp, $parts[0] );   
    fclose( $fp );      
}
?>
```

Comment: А вариант с кодированием картинки в строку и чтением на стороне PHP с помощью createimagefromstring? Т.е. есть ли вариант на флеш стороне конвертации картинки в стринг?

Comment: сек, где то было :)

Comment: на стороне пхп не знаю как со строкой обращаться

    var base64String:String;
    var ba:ByteArray = (o.filedata as ByteArray)
    base64String = Base64X.encode(ba);
    request.data = base64String;

класс Base64X например тут - http://www.sociodox.com/base64.html

Comment: еще совет небольшой:

    navigateToURL(request, "_blank"); 

оч желательно заменить на URLLoader:

    var loader = new URLLoader();
    loader.load(request);

Чтоб с флешки не уходил браузер по урлу.